# An impossible sequence of Tetris pieces.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a finite sequence of pieces of Tetris such that for every way of play you always lose?

Comment: I assume you mean a "standard set" of Tetris pieces?  It is simple to come up with a piece such that if that piece is repeated you will always lose.

Comment: Also, what are the dimensions of the Tetris board used?  If such a sequence exists, it is likely to be dependent on these dimensions.

Comment: It's worth noting that modern versions of Tetris don't draw pieces randomly; it hands out a random permutation of each of the 7 pieces before creating a new permutation, so you'll at most see 12 other pieces before seeing the same piece again. Then there's also the "hold" mechanic which lets you save a piece for later.

Comment: Wait, so is it or isn't it true that the line piece is drawn with decreased probability?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A game of Tetris (on a 10×20 grid) consisting of alternating S and Z tetrominoes will necessarily end before 70000 tetrominoes are played.

http://euclid.trentu.ca/aejm/V4N1/Tsuruda.V4N1.pdf — Lemma 2.

Answer (score 13):

### Not anymore.

Older versions of *Tetris* had a uniform stateless randomizer. This would allow a repeating SZ-sequence that eventually causes a loss. This is possible yet unfathomably unlikely in practice because a competent player can survive this sequence for 150 Tetriminos on a standard 10x20-cell matrix, and the odds of an ideal randomizer producing this sequence are 1 in (7/2)<sup>150</sup> = 4×10<sup>81</sup>, roughly one in the number of atoms in the observable universe.

But since 2001, the randomizer rule in *Tetris Worlds*, *Tetris DS*, and other authentic *Tetris* games has been the "bag" rule, called "[Random Generator](http://harddrop.com/wiki/Random_Generator)" by *Tetris* developer Blue Planet Software. It deals a permutation of the seven distinct Tetriminos (5,040 possibilities), then reshuffles, then deals another permutation, etc. An SZ-sequence longer than length 4 is forbidden because a sequence of length 4 has to be sandwiched between two permutations of IJLOT.

It turns out that if you keep a pile of S, T, and Z in columns 1-4 of a 10x20-cell matrix, and J, L, and O in columns 7-10, you can enter a pattern that repeats every 140 Tetriminos and thus extend the game indefinitely. In 2007, Colour Thief released a proof of this, titled "[Playing forever](http://harddrop.com/wiki/Playing_forever)". The following tiling of a 10x56-cell rectangle should help you grasp the pattern used by the proof.

[image: The "Playing forever" tiling]

Answer (score 2):

If the board has odd width (any length is fine) then yes, there is trivially such a sequence. Just assume all pieces are the $2 \times 2$ squares. So maybe you should insist that the board width is even?

Comment: The standard board has even dimensions. I believe it's 10x20, but I could be wrong.